# Canonical forms for tensors of type (2,1)

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, invariant-theory

Are there any canonical forms for tensors of type (2,1)? Such a tensor can be defined as a bi-linear map $$ T:V \times V \rightarrow V,$$ for $V$ a finitely dimensional real vector space.

Comment: What do you mean by "canonical form"? Do you have any examples?

Comment: @Daniel For a (1,1) tensor( an endomorphism of V ) there is the Jordan canonical form. For a symmetric tensor of type (2,0) one can find a base in which its matrix is diagonal(with only $\pm 1$ or zero on the diagonal).

Answer (score 1):

I think that in some sense there can't be any "worthwhile" canonical form:

If $V$ is $n$-dimensional then the space of such tensors is $n^3$-dimensional, and $GL(V)$ is only $n^2$-dimensional. So any canonical form would have $n^3-n^2$ degrees of freedom, which is almost as many as if you didn't use the canonical form.

Comment: What if the (2,1) tensor has some symmetries. Let say the tensor $$T:V\times V \rightarrow V$$ is symmetric, that is $$ T(X,Y)=T(Y,X) \,\ \forall X,Y \in V.$$ In the simple case when $\dim V=2,$ there is always a base of $V$ $, (e_1,e_2)$ such that $$ T(e_1,e_2)=T(e_2,e_1)=0$$ and $$ T(e_1,e_1)=T(e_2,e_2).$$ Clearly one can call the 3 dimensional matrix of such a tensor a canonical form.

Comment: I'm not sure if your statement about the canonical form is true, for example what about multiplication in $\mathbb C$ thought of as an $\mathbb R$ vector space? This is definitely commutative but there no two non-zero complex numbers with $\alpha\beta=0$.

Anyway, I was only really thinking about canonical forms that work in arbitrary dimension, like JNF, in which case I don't think there are any interesting canonical forms unless you impose enough symmetries to make the degrees of freedom $O(n^2)$.